# Compiling legacy VB6 components - make error

Tags: vb6, makefile, legacy-code

OK, so I have the joyous task of writing a command-line build for a bunch of legacy VB6 ActiveX DLLs (so that we can integrate this into our TFS builds).

I've installed a copy of VB6 on our build server, and I'm trying, as a first step, to get one of the projects building from the command line thusly:

```
> VB6.EXE /make path\to\project.vbp
```

The result is an error dialog telling me:

```
Unexpected error occurred in code generator or linker. [OK] [Help]
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of a solution, or at least give me a hint? Thanking any respondants in advance!

**Edit**

It's a cross-project dependency issue. Dammit.

Comment: Can you build the project successfully from within the VB 6 IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm an idiot - turns out that the components depend on each other in various undocumented ways, and they have to be compiled in a specific order which has long since been lost.

So now I'm trawling through 30+ VB projects and documenting the dependencies :)

Thanks for those who answered anyway, sorry to waste your time.

Comment: +1 You are using binary compatibility right? There are [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523612/should-you-build-components-every-time-you-build-a-main-app) other [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378669/how-to-do-development-and-build-in-visual-basic-6-0) on here from people in similar situations. Mostly they just build the projects in the particular order, as you describe.

Comment: +1 for the binary compatibility comment. In a project like that, you'll definitely want to investigate handling that properly if it's not already.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to use `/makedll` switch - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231236(VS.60).aspx